# %temp% etc not working

Tags: powershell

I have the below that is used as a batch file that launches powershell (too long to go over but it is used in another script).

Anyway, I noticed the %systemroot%\temp and %systemroot% does not work.

Any idea how I can fix this?

```
%systemroot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File %SystemRoot%\TEMP\ROFS\testing_script_log.ps1
```

Thanks,

Comment: Done on my system works great. Which is the error you have?

Comment: your right Christian....my stupidity...the path is incorrect!! Would have worked in the end!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you are executing that line from PowerShell rather than from CMD, you can use the PowerShell environment variable syntax:

```
PS C:\> & "$env:SystemRoot\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
```

Comment: I wanted to know this as well - so thanks for answering it. The actual fault was the path was incorrect - this is fixed now but good to know the above.

Comment: I'm a huge noob. Why do you need the "&" at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables to expand environment variables within a string the old-fashioned way.

```
$s = '%systemroot%\temp'
[Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($s)
```

Comment: Useful with PowerShell 2.0 (Windows 2008) where "$env.SYSTEMROOT" does not work

Comment: actually it is `$s = [Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($s)`

Answer (score 0):

**Successfully verified with below code C#.**

//**file location - User Variables**
string fileLocation = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FILE_PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
//**file location - System Variables**
string fileLocation = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_FILE_PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);

On Powershell script

```
& "D:\Visual_Studio_Workspace\AzureUpload\AzureUpload\bin\Debug\AzureUpload.exe"
```

AzureUpload.exe -- contain the above code C# code as Console application (Visual_Studio_Workspace\AzureUpload\AzureUpload\bin\Debug{.exe file location})